# Disable a key in windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard, acer-aspire

The laptop keyboard has been giving me some problems over the past couple of days with the home and end keys 'acting' like struck at any random point of time.

'Acting' as in , they dont seem struck but i am continuously pulled to the top or bottom of what I am doing, leaving me frustrated.

So is there any software out there, by which i can disable Home,pageup,page down and end keys totally so that even if they are pressed, nothing happens.

Googling only helped me with key remappers and since i use a lot of applications, i dont know which key to remap these 4 to, as all function keys have some or the other command in each software I use.  So guys, plaese help.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just accidently touching the touchpad while typing?

Comment: No man, i just opened my facebook homepage and left it and it was going down and down like crazy, just like someone was hitting end button endlesssly. so yea am sure its not me touching the touchpad

Comment: Does it do it in Safe Mode as well?  How about in the BIOS or  another OS (say a Linux LiveCD)?

Comment: am not that fan of linux man, moreoever i have limited internetf acilities and changing my OS right now is not at all an option for atleast 3 more months, so that's why i am going for disabling the keys in windows

Comment: The reason I suggest testing with Safe Mode and another OS is to ensure the key(s) are actually faulty and that it's not software causing it.  Perhaps check out [How to test which button is stuck](http://superuser.com/questions/27809/how-to-test-which-button-is-stuck?rq=1) to help you determine which key(s) are the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable or reassign the 'Windows' key?](http://superuser.com/questions/1384/how-can-i-disable-or-reassign-the-windows-key) also see [How can I disable and reassign the Caps Lock key?](http://superuser.com/questions/1193/how-can-i-disable-and-reassign-the-caps-lock-key/1250#1250).  Both these contain answers that can be used with just about any key(s).

Comment: Anyway for the sake of anyone who happens upon to come by this thread in the future, i used this software called sharpkeys which absolutely rendered the end and home keys nonfunctional, exactly what I was looking for.